# How to set 'rotate()' value to match current time?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a clock in javascript. I can't figure out how to set the value of rotate() equal to the degree of the current time.

I've tried some methods.
I've looked at these tutorials:

- https://cssanimation.rocks/clocks/
- https://medium.com/@abhi95.saxena/make-an-analog-clock-using-javascript-7c07580ea91b

This is what I have right now and I believe it should work like this.

HTML:

```
 <div class="analogClock">
    <div class="hours-container" id="pointer">
        <div class="hours"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="minutes-container" id="pointer">
        <div class="minutes"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="second-container" id="pointer">
        <div class="seconds"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.analogClock{
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #11052B;
    height: 20em;
    width: 20em;
    position: relative;
}

.second-container, .minutes-container, .hours-container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.hours{
    background-color: #E83063;
    height: 20%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    width: 2.5%;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.minutes{
    background-color: #6CE4FF;
    height: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    width: 2%;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.seconds{
    background-color: #59FF8C;
    height: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    width: 1%;
    z-index: 8;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.hours-container{
    animation: rotate 43200s infinite steps(12);
}

.minutes-container{
    animation: rotate 3600s infinite steps(60);
}

.second-container{
    animation: rotate 60s infinite steps(60);
}

@keyframes rotate {
    100% { transform: rotateZ(360deg); }
}
```

JS:

```
//Analog clock
const hourPointer = document.querySelector('.hours-container');
const minutePointer = document.querySelector('.minutes-container');
const secondPointer = document.querySelector('.second-container');


function analogClock(){
    var date = new Date();
    var seconds = date.getSeconds();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var hours = date.getHours();

    let hrPosition = hours*360/12 + ((minutes * 360/60)/12) ;
    let minPosition = (minutes * 360/60) + (seconds* 360/60)/60;
    let secPosition = seconds * 360/60;

    hourPointer.getElementsByClassName.transform = 'rotate(' + hrPosition + 'deg)';
    minutePointer.getElementsByClassName.transform = 'rotate(' + minPosition + 'deg)';
    secondPointer.getElementsByClassName.transform = 'rotate(' + secPosition + 'deg)';
}

var interval = setInterval(analogClock, 500)
```

I want the hands to point at the current time, but they start from the bottom no matter what time it is.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Please may I have the css and html for this? I am working on a fix for you but want to give you a correct, tested answer.

Comment: Ofcourse! I'll update the post in a sec.

Comment: shouldn't be `hours*360/12` change to `hours * (360/12)`?

Comment: Make id="pointer" a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have attempted to get you as much in here as possible, you should see a fully working clock. It's not been done too different from your current version.

```js
 (function ($) {

  var secondHand = $('.second-hand');
  var minuteHand = $('.minute-hand');
  var hourHand = $('.hour-hand');

  function analogClock(){
   var date = new Date();
   var seconds = date.getSeconds();
   var minutes = date.getMinutes();
   var hours = date.getHours();
   //console.log(date);
   //console.log(seconds);
   //console.log(minutes);
   //console.log(hours);

   seconds = (360 / 100) * ((seconds / 60) * 100);
   minutes = (360 / 100) * ((minutes / 60) * 100);
   hours = (360 / 100) * ((hours / 12) * 100);

   var secondsAngle = seconds;
   var minutesAngle = minutes;
   var hoursAngle = hours;
   //console.log(secondsAngle);
   //console.log(minutesAngle);
   //console.log(hoursAngle);

   secondHand.css({
    '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ secondsAngle +'deg)',
    '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ secondsAngle +'deg)',
    '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ secondsAngle +'deg)',
    'transform' : 'rotate('+ secondsAngle +'deg)'
   });

   minuteHand.css({
    '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ minutesAngle +'deg)',
    '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ minutesAngle +'deg)',
    '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ minutesAngle +'deg)',
    'transform' : 'rotate('+ minutesAngle +'deg)'
   });

   hourHand.css({
    '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ hoursAngle +'deg)',
    '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ hoursAngle +'deg)',
    '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ hoursAngle +'deg)',
    'transform' : 'rotate('+ hoursAngle +'deg)'
   });
  }

  setInterval(function() {

   analogClock();

  }, 1000);

 })(jQuery);
```

```css
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 .clock {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: purple;
 }
 .clock-face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
 }
  .hand {
   height: 100px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   transform-origin: 50% 100%;
   display: block;
  }

  .second-hand {
   width: 5px;
   z-index: 3;
  }
   .sec-hand {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
   }
  .minute-hand {
   width: 6px;
   z-index: 2;
  }
   .min-hand {
    height: 80px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: green;
   }
  .hour-hand {
   width: 7px;
   z-index: 1;
  }
   .hr-hand {
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    background-color: black;
   }

   .single-hand {
    width: 100%;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clock">
  <div class="clock-face">
   <div class="second-hand hand">
    <div class="sec-hand single-hand"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="minute-hand hand">
    <div class="min-hand single-hand"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="hour-hand hand">
    <div class="hr-hand single-hand"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

- Just updated to order the hands (z-index) and change their length...

**The Math:**

```
seconds = (360 / 100) * ((seconds / 60) * 100);
minutes = (360 / 100) * ((minutes / 60) * 100);
hours = (360 / 100) * ((hours / 12) * 100);s
```

**(360 / 100):** So for all of the time variables, there is 360deg of possible rotation.
We divide by 100, to give us a single percent of the clocks face.

**a * b:** We now can multiply this by a percentage of the clock (the math above) to represent how far in degrees we will need to rotate the hand.

**((seconds / 60) * 100):** We need to then create a value that is a percentage of the way through a full rotation.

This can be done by taking the number of seconds, minutes, hours given by the new date(); dividing it by the total possible 60 seconds, 60 minutes, 12 hours.
We then must multiply it by 100% to get a percentage.

**The whole result:** One seconds worth of rotation * percentage of the way through one full turn.

**e.g:** 1 second worth of rotation * 50% of the way through a complete minute = 180deg / 30seconds

Hope that makes sense...

Comment: Im an idiot, I have started the clock at 3:15:15. Let me fix this.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to create such a comprehensive solution Jason! I learned a lot from it! I got a view points I don't understand and if it isn't to much trouble I'd like to get more info about: How the math works u used to get the correct angle and if you could point me to a source where I can see how the ajax and jquery code u used works. 

You're probably a busy man so please don't feel obligated to answer my questions.

Comment: No problemo @Jeroen, glad you like it. You can see the math explained at the tail of my answer.

Comment: Thank you Jason! I really apreciate it! One last question about the math. Isn't (seconds / 60 * 100) the same as ((seconds / 60) * 100). Or do the inner parenthesis change something?

Comment: Because you are multiplying the first value by the second value you need to contain the two equations separate from each other. seconds = (360 / 100) * ((seconds / 60) * 100); will return a different value to seconds = (360 / 100) * (seconds / 60) * 100;. I have also spotted a typo in my css - please change your .clock-face css rule to be position: relative; not display: relative;

Comment: Alright! Thanks again for your time! I'm done bothering you for now ;).

Comment: I guess that means I should do my own work then! :c